# Faster way to create large BufferedImages

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am looking for a faster way to create large (12291x12291) BufferedImages.  I am using Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics() to draw on it, saving it to a file, then using g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); to load it.  I am saving the file so I can load a particular image later.  As of now, it takes around 45 seconds to one minute to create the image.  Is there any way to create these images faster?

I am creating two of these images.

```
public void drawTiles() {       
    Graphics2D g2d = tiles1.createGraphics();

    left = 0;
    top = 0;
    //The drawing takes around 10 to 20 seconds
    Colors c = new Colors();
    for (double[] row : data) {
        for (double d : row) {
            int v = (int) (20 - d / 500);
            if (v < 0) {
                v = 0;
            } else if (v > 20) {
                v = 20;
            }
            color = v;
            g2d.setColor(c.colors[color]);

            g2d.fillRect(left, top, sizeX, sizeY);
            left += sizeX;
            if (left == size * sizeX) {
                left = 0;
                top += sizeY;

            }
        }
    }     
    g2d.dispose();

    //The creation of the file takes little time for an image of this size
    try {
        File tiles1file = new File("path/to/map" + id + ".bmp");
        ImageIO.write(tiles1, "bmp", tiles1file);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    id++;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the "creating an image" is the part taking a long time? Could you show your code?

Comment: Compressing and decompressing PNGs (which uses DEFLATE) isn't exactly fast compared to creating an image from scratch entirely in memory.

Comment: However, how about try BMP files? They are uncompressed, and mainly limited by disk speed (~100 MB/s). Your 12291×12291 image would take about 450 MB.

Comment: I tried using creating BMP files and there was a a difference in speed (It took around 30 seconds), but is that small time difference worth the extra space?  Is their something I can do to speed it up further?

Comment: 1. Try setting RenderingHints on g2d to "Performance". 2. Swap row and column to match the Java2D-internal coordinates of BufferedImage. 3. Rewrite your code, so that no BufferedImages are never larger than 1M-Pixels (which is about the limit after they are processed in RAM rather than VRAM)

Answer (score 1):

I would move `Colors c = new Colors();` outside of all loops.  Creating and garbage-collecting that object every time will slow things down, at least until the JIT figures out that it can be optimized.

Since disk access is far slower than computation, you can try maximizing the compression of the PNG by setting the quality to zero:

```
try (ImageOutputStream out = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(tiles1file)) {
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();
    writer.setOutput(out);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(0);

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(tiles1, null, null), param);
}
```